# Quick Math Number Problem Converting 10 to 7.5

Tags: statistics

**Quick Math Problem**

I have a mark list . the total Marks are 10 . Now i have to roundup each total Marks to 7.5

Also i have to roundup Obtained Marks List to 7.5.

> IS their any mathematical Solution to this problem

---------------------- |

|Obtained Marks|

9

7.5

7.5

6.5

6.5

7

6

7

9

5.5

7

7.5

8.5

6.5

6.5

8.5

6

7

---------------------- |

Comment: I'm unclear on the question. So are the marks are out of 10? Also what to you mean by by "roundup each total marks to 7.5"?

Comment: Marks are out of 10 , in Simple Words convert 10 to 7.5 and then give obtained marks from 7.5. as you can see the obtained marks are given from out of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i get it now i have to divide obtained mark with 10 and then multiply it with 7.5

> Obtained Marks / 10 * 7.5 = 6.7 (roundof) = 7.0

As Example Let's See this

> 10 / 10 * 7.5 = 7.5

Comment: This does make the mark out of 7.5 now (and then of course you can round up if you want). Well done for working on it and answering your own question. +1!